# How to efficiently find almost identical substrings of a specified length in a collection of strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching, string-comparison, dna-sequence

My question is similar to [How to efficiently find identical substrings of a specified length in a collection of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52509368/how-to-efficiently-find-identical-substrings-of-a-specified-length-in-a-collecti)

Let's assume that I have `t` strings, each one is at length `n`
and I need to find a substring at length `k` that has at most one index that is not identical and it needs to be the same index in every string, for example, consider the following 4 strings:

AC**TAGG**GGT

**TAGG**AAACC

CCCGG**TTGG**

G**TGGG**ACTG

The output, in this case, should be: `T*GG and S = (3,1,6,2)`
where S is the starting index of the substring in each string Si.